# How to load values from a plist?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, plist

I'm loading the data from a plist and am trying to find out how to access data from each item. In the following code I'd like to be able to extract the value of text and whether it's checked = 0 or checked = 1

I've tried this:

```
    NSString *dataArray1 = [[dataArray objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:2];
```

but was wondering if that is the best approach

thanks for any help.

```
// load data from a plist file inside our app bundle
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Providers" ofType:@"plist"];
dataArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSLog(@"data array from offers %@", dataArray);
```

Here's the output:

```
2013-01-21 15:13:34.599 data array from offers (
        {
        checked = 1;
        text = Provider1;
    },
        {
        checked = 1;
        text = Provider2;
    },
        {
        checked = 1;
        text = Provider3;
    },
        {
        checked = 1;
        text = Provider4;
    }
)
```

So I'd like to be able to find out what the checked value of each item. That Provider4 is set to 1 and Provider3 is 0 etc... then use that to pass in parameters to a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Providers" ofType:@"plist"];
dataArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in dataArray)
  {
  NSString *text = [dictionary valueForKey:@"text"];
  NSNumber *checked = [dictionary valueForKey:@"checked"];
  NSLog(@"%@ checked value is: %@", text, checked);
}
```

Comment: any idea how I might ask for to only show the providers where checked == 1?

Answer (score 1):

something like this, i guess:

```
for (id dict in dataArray)
  int checked = [[(NSDictionary *)dict objectForKey:@"checked"] intValue];
```